# Change first byte of s_addr

Tags: c++

I would like to set the first byte of an **s_addr** variable, which is just an unsigned long.
Is this possible, and if so, how?

It is not an array of bytes, so I can't access it like this:

```
struct in_addr addr;
addr.s_addr[0] = 1; // Set this byte to the number 1, or in hex: 0x01
```

EDIT:

It turns out that I needed the last (i.e. the 4th) byte and not the first. But thanks to your help I now have:

```
*((char *)&addr.s_addr + 3) = 1;
```

Comment: `memcpy(addr+4,1UL,1);` or `*(addr+4)=*(char *)(&ulong);` i'm not sure what you exactly mean...

Comment: there is no `struct s_addr`, isn't it: `struct in_addr { unsigned long s_addr; };` and if this is the same in your implementation, I should imagine a bitwise operation should do the trick...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One ugly and possibly unsafe (but nevertheless widely practised) way is like this:

```
*(char *)&addr.s_addr = 42;
```

If you know that `addr.s_addr` is an `unsigned long` though, and if by "first" byte you mean "least significant" byte, then you can use bitwise operators as a much safer alternative, e.g.

```
addr.s_addr &= ~0xffUL; // clear previous contents of LS byte
addr.s_addr |=  0x01UL; // set LS byte to 1
```

Comment: Could you explain why this could be unsafe?

Comment: It's called "type punning" and it breaks aliasing rules in C and C++ - if you're going to resort to this kind of low level nastiness then it's probably a good idea to compile without strict aliasing, e.g. `gcc -fno-strict-alising ...`. I've now added a safer alternative method using bitwise operators.

Comment: And if I were to change the most significant byte. I would go like this: addr.s_addr &= ~0xff000000; addr.s_addr |= 0x01000000; Or is there a better way?

Comment: @Oxidator: yes, that's perfectly fine - it depends on what you mean by "better", but to me it's safe, readable and robust.

Answer (score 2):

You take its address, interpret it as a pointer to a `char` and dereference it:

```
unsigned long ul;
*reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ul) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// ina is struct sockaddr_in
char* address = a1 = inet_ntoa(ina.sin_addr);
*address = x;

or

*(char*)&addr.s_addr = x;
```

Comment: There are other ways obviously, but I would like to skip the conversion part for this.